# how to be able to add records using Http Methods on django

Tags: json, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm creating a Django rest API  authentication system and I want to return data in JSON format,the main purpose of this question is : I want to add or delete users only by adding fields on json format , not in the inputs that've created :

**this is my views.py :**

```
# Rendering plant data as json :
def plant_json(request):
    data=list(new_Plant.objects.values())
    return JsonResponse(data,safe=False)
```

this is my output ( don't mind the values )  :

```
[{"id": 5, "name": "dqsd", "adress": "sdq", "type": "PV", "location": "dqd", "list_gateway": "gggdds", "status": "etude"}, {"id": 6, "name": "fdsfds", "adress": "fsdfds", "type": "PV", "location": "fdsfds", "list_gateway": "fdsfs", "status": "etude"}, {"id": 7, "name": "sdqdssd", "adress": "dsdsq", "type": "HYBRID", "location": "dqsdqs", "list_gateway": "dsdqss", "status": "online"}]
```

normally in order to add a new plant I've created a HTML template that has inputs where the user can add a plant , but what I want is that I can add a plant only by adding fields directly using json format ( using postman for example ) no need for the inputs. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use is a `CreateAPIView` (see docs [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#createapiview)). All you need to do is to define the serializer you need and use it in the view.

```py
# serializers.py
from models import Plant
from rest_framework import serializers

class PlantSerialzer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Plant
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'address', 'type', 'location', 'list_gateway', 'status')

# views.py
from my_plant_module.serializers import PlantSerializer
from rest_framework.generics import CreateAPIView

class PlantCreateView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Plant.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PlantSerializer
```